# Selenium Webdriver can't use verifyEquals()

Tags: selenium, phpunit

How can I use `verifyEquals()` in selenium webdriver?
I've been searching the net but all I can find are samples from Java
.. by the way, I am using `Netbeans IDE` and `PHP` language

```
$that->verifyEquals($cost,$total,"Not Equal!!!");
```

it displays an error like this `Exception: You cannot call a command with multiple method arguments.`

Comment: Where do you want to use. Can you please show the code.

Comment: $that->assertEquals($cost,$total,"Not Equal!!!");

-i want to make it to verifyEquals but it doesn't seem to work

it displays an error like this "Exception: You cannot call a command with multiple method arguments."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try using try-catch exception.. it worked on me